# Java WebService - WebSphere Application Server

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, websphere

I need to run a webservice on a WebSphere Application Server (Liberty Profile) so I can get the wsdl and use it to make tests on SoapUI.
I'm using WebSphere Developer Tools on Eclipse Luna.

I have the code for this webservice, as follows:

**Communicate.java**

```
package xpto;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface Communicate {
        @WebMethod String initiate(String var);
}
```

**CommunicateImpl.java**

```
package xpto;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "xpto.Communicate")
public class CommunicateImpl implements Communicate {
    @Override
    public String initiate(String var){
        System.out.println("Communicating");
        return "S";
    }
}
```

Now, what should I do to run the webservice and get the wsdl file?

Comment: did you try something like http://localhost:<port>/<yourAppName>/Communicate?wsdl

Comment: @vincent yes I did. I get this: 
Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /Communicate

Comment: and what about with CommunicateImpl instead of Communicate ?

Comment: Yes, also tried that. Was actually going to say that in the previous comment but forgot to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check your web service name in the Eclipse. Expand your web project then `JAX-WS Web Services > Web Services`. Your service is probably called `CommunicateImplService`, so wsdl should be accessible by: `http://host:port/context/serviceName?wsdl` in your case probably `CommunicateImplService?wsdl`. Also make sure that your project is added to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel,

Try giving an action attribute to the webmethod annotation.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/reference/tutorials/wsit/doc/Examples_netbeans3.html

Comment: Did you run wsgen to generate the webservice artificats.  Your Websphere Developer Tools might provide an option to run it.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE a WAR file.DEPLOY it on WEBSPHERE.give context path name then access the webservice in url 
using Http:// ipadress:port/contextpath/webservice name?wsdl